# Performance issues building graph with py2neo transactions

Tags: performance, neo4j, transactions, cypher, py2neo

I'm trying to build a full binary tree of variable depth using py2neo. I've been trying to use py2neo transactions to send create statements to the server, but the runtime awful.

Building a tree with depth 8 (255 nodes) takes about 16.7 seconds - the vast majority of that time is spent while the transaction is committing (if I Transaction.process() before committing then the processing takes the bulk of the runtime). What could be the issue? The cypher statements are each just a single Match and a node + relationship Create.

Here's the function which builds the tree

```
def buildBinaryTree(self):
    depth = 1
    tx = self.graph.begin()
    g = self.graph
    leaves = []
    leaves.append("Root")
    tx.run('CREATE(n {ruleName: "Root"})')
    timeSum = 0
    while depth < self.scale:
        newLeaves = []
        for leaf in leaves:
            leftName = leaf + 'L'
            rightName = leaf + 'R'
            newLeaves.append(leftName)
            newLeaves.append(rightName)
            start = timer()

            statement = ('MATCH(n {ruleName: "' + leaf + '"}) '
                        'WITH n CREATE (n)-[:`LINKS TO`]'
                        '->({ruleName: "' + leftName + '"})')
            tx.run(statement)
            statement = ('MATCH(n {ruleName: "' + leaf + '"}) '
                        'WITH n CREATE (n)-[:`LINKS TO`]'
                        '->(m {ruleName: "' + rightName + '"})')
            tx.run(statement)
            end = timer()
            timeSum += (end - start)
        leaves = newLeaves
        depth += 1
        print("Depth = " + str(depth))

    print(timeSum)
    start = timer()
    print("Processing...")
    tx.process()
    print (timer() - start)
    print("Committing...")
    tx.commit()
    print("Committed")
    print (timer() - start)
```

And the output with scale = 8

```
building tree...
Depth = 2
Depth = 3
Depth = 4
Depth = 5
Depth = 6
Depth = 7
Depth = 8
0.009257960999775605
Processing...
16.753949095999815
Committing...
Committed
17.28687257200022
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using so others can help figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try making these changes to ensure that you are truly running in a single transaction and not unnecessarily delaying committing your updates:

- Change `tx.run` to `tx.append`. That will enqueue each Cypher statement instead of immediately executing it.
- Delete `tx.process()`, since you have no subsequent Cypher statements to enqueue.

Ideally, you should also be passing parameters instead of modifying your Cypher statements every time through the loop. However, that would not be responsible for the slowness you are experiencing.

Comment: I tried tx.append(), no effect on runtime. Removing tx.process also has no effect, I just had it there to demonstrate that whatever process() does is what is taking so long.

Comment: How many nodes are there in the DB? Your query is doing 256 complete node scans.

Comment: The DB is empty prior to execution. I'm trying to automate the DB build for testing purposes. I think I'll resort to writing to CSV files and importing from there, since it's just for an initial build. Should be much faster anyway